# C++ Changing Struct to Class

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I am doing linked list exercises and currently understand how to write a link list in struct format. However I would like to change my code to make linked list a class and have the print, sort, add, delete, functions as members of the class. Please give me ideas on how this can be done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;
struct mylist {
    int payload;
    struct mylist * link;
};

void addlink(struct mylist *, int);
struct mylist * droplink(struct mylist *);
void printmylist(struct mylist *);
void sortmylist(struct mylist *);
int main() {
    struct mylist head;
    struct mylist *lptr;
    head.payload = 15;
    head.link = 0;
    lptr = &head;
    printmylist(lptr);
    addlink(lptr, 21);
    printmylist(lptr);
    addlink(lptr, -5);
    printmylist(lptr);
    addlink(lptr, 90);
    printmylist(lptr);
    lptr = droplink(lptr);
    printmylist(lptr);
    sortmylist(lptr);
    printmylist(lptr);
    return 0;
}
void addlink(struct mylist *lp, int val) {
    struct mylist *temp;
    struct mylist *newlink;
    //run out to end of chain
    temp = lp;
    do {
        if (temp->link != 0)
            temp = temp->link;
    } while (temp->link != 0);
    newlink = (struct mylist *) malloc(sizeof(struct mylist));
    newlink->payload = val;
    newlink->link = 0;
    temp->link = newlink;
    return;
}
struct mylist * droplink(struct mylist *lp) {
    cout << "Releasing front value of " << lp->payload << endl;
    return lp->link;
}

void printmylist(struct mylist *lp) {
    struct mylist *temp;
    temp = lp;
    while (temp->link != 0) {
        cout << temp->payload << " then ";//if there is just one link, loop never runs
        if (temp->link != 0)
            temp = temp->link;
    }
    cout << temp->payload; //gets the last link's value
    cout << endl;
    return;
}
void sortmylist(struct mylist *lp) {
    struct mylist *temp;
    struct mylist *temp2;
    int linkcount = 1;
    int temppayload;
    temp = lp;
    while (temp->link != 0) {
        if (temp->link != 0) {
            ++linkcount;
            temp = temp->link;
        }
    }
    cout << linkcount << " links " << endl;
    temp = lp;
    for (int ct2 = 1; ct2 < linkcount; ++ct2) {
        temp = lp;
        for (int ct = 1; ct < linkcount; ++ct) {

            if (temp->link != 0)
                temp2 = temp->link;

            if (temp->payload > temp2->payload) {
                temppayload = temp->payload;
                temp->payload = temp2->payload;
                temp2->payload = temppayload;

            }
            if (temp2->link != 0)
                temp = temp2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to turn it into a class?

Comment: `struct` and `class` are basically the same in C++. You can express exactly the same types using either. So I think you may need to re-phrase the question, particularly the title.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are almost identical, the only difference is that `structs` members are `public` by default, whereas `class` members are `private` by default. If you specify `public:` before your `class` members, you should be fine

Comment: This is too open-ended and conversational. You should read your C++ book again to learn how to write classes with member functions. We won't write you a tutorial on that, here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The only real difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C++ is that by default all members of a `class` are private, and all members of a `struct` are public.

I assume what you're really asking is how to make your linked list methods *members* of your struct / class. This is very easy.

All of your existing methods accept a `struct mylist*` as the first parameter. In C++, this is provided automatically by the compiler, as a hidden parameter called `this`. You can refer to `this` explicitly, but it is also accessible implicitly.

So where in C you might have:

```
lp->payload = 0;
```

In a C++ class member function, you could have:

```
this->payload = 0;
```

Or more commonly:

```
payload = 0;
```

So broadly speaking, the steps required to "c++ify" your C code are:

- Move the declarations of the methods into the body of the `struct`
- Remove the `struct mylist *` argument from each method
- Remove the references to `lp` in each method
- Call the member functions by dereferencing an instance of the `struct` (e.g. `lptr->addlink(-5);`)

Comment: There's another difference between `struct` and `class`: default inheritance is `public` in the former and `private` in the latter.

Comment: That's true, but it never comes up in practice because nobody uses default inheritance (for any reasonable coding standard).

Comment: I up-voted this answer because it got most of the way there, but I want to add a key explanation: 

When you go from a C-style structure to an object oriented approach (or at least C++'s object oriented approach), it's important to note that the **data and the operations on the data are now coupled**.  That is _why_ you are moving the functions that used to exist outside of the struct definition into the class definition.  Also, those functions (now referred to as methods) access the data using the this-> accessor because the data is in "this" object (unless a static method).

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, you can change every struct that is passed to a linked list function from:

```
struct Node {
    int payload;
    struct Node *link;
};
...
void addlink(struct Node *lp, int val) {
...
}
```

to this:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node() : _link(0), _payload(0) { }  // initialize members on new empty node
    Node(int val) : _link(0), _payload(val) { } // pass a new value directly

    ~Node() { 
        // call a function to clear everything pointed to from _link
    }

    void addlink(int val) {
        Node *temp = this;
        do {
            if (temp->link() != 0)
                temp = temp->link();
        } while (temp->link() != 0);

        Node *newlink = new Node(val); // this will do what the next 2 lines do

        //Node *newlink = new Node;  <- you can also create a Node this way and then assign the payload
        //newlink->setPayload(val);

        // newlink->link = 0;  <-- not needed 'new Node' has already initialized it

        temp->setLink(newlink);
    }

// provide access to the data (get/set)

    int payload() { return _payload; }
    void setPayload(int n) { _payload = n; }
    Node *link() { return _link; }
    void setLink(Node *p) { _link = p; }

// data members
private:
    int _payload;
    Node *_link;
};
```

This fragment gives you the idea. Now you can add the rest :)
The best of course, is to place the code within the functions in a .cpp file and leave the definition of the class in the header:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(int val); // pass a new value directly

    ~Node();

    void addlink(int val);

// provide access to the data (get/set)
// you can leave thse one liners in the header, they'll most likely be inlined
    int payload() { return _payload; }
    void setPayload(int n) { _payload = n; }
    Node *link() { return _link; }
    void setLink(Node *p) { _link = p; }

// data members
private:
    int _payload;
    Node *_link;
};
```

The bodies of the functions in the cpp:

```
Node::Node() : _link(0), _payload(0)
{
}

Node::Node(int val) : _link(0), _payload(val) 
{
}

......
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was adding struct node into the class LinkedList and making a confusing mess.

Comment: After you define a struct or a class in C++, you no longer need to use the keywords when you declare variables of the types you defined.